# Highlighting some nodes of a TikZ binomial tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, highlighting

In this binomial tree I have 4 columns of nodes.

I want the entire last column to be highlighted with light blue, and perhaps a border around this highlighting. Something like a opaque blue-ish rectangle or thin oval highlighting the entire last column of nodes.

Just started with TikZ and nothing is working so far.

I'm using pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
      \matrix (tree) [%
        matrix of nodes,
        minimum size=1cm,
        column sep=3.5cm,
        row sep=1cm,
      ]
      {
                &                    &                     &  $^\tau S_0$     \\
                &                    &  $^{2\Delta t}S_0$  &              \\
                & $^{\Delta t}S_0$   &                     &  $^\tau S_1$     \\
        $^0S_0$ &                    &  $^{2\Delta t}S_1$  &              \\
                & $^{\Delta t}S_1$  &                      &  $^\tau S_2$     \\
                &                    &  $^{2\Delta t}S_2$  &              \\
                &                    &                     &  $^\tau S_2$     \\
      };
      \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
      \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
      \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};

    \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two solutions. First solution uses `column 4` style to add a border and to fill each node in fourth column of your matrix. Second solution uses `fit` and `background` libraries to put a new node on background fitting `tree-1-4` and `tree-7-4` nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
  \matrix (tree) [%
  matrix of nodes,
  minimum size=1cm,
  column sep=3.5cm,
  row sep=1cm,
  % fill and draw each node of fourth column 
  column 4/.style={nodes={draw,fill=cyan!30,rounded corners}},
  ]
  {
            &                  &                   & $^\tau S_0$ \\
            &                  & $^{2\Delta t}S_0$ &             \\
            & $^{\Delta t}S_0$ &                   & $^\tau S_1$ \\
    $^0S_0$ &                  & $^{2\Delta t}S_1$ &             \\
            & $^{\Delta t}S_1$ &                   & $^\tau S_2$ \\
            &                  & $^{2\Delta t}S_2$ &             \\
            &                  &                   & $^\tau S_2$ \\
  };
  \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
  \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
  \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};

  \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
  \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

  % put a new node on background fitting (tree-1-4) and (tree-7-4) nodes
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit=(tree-1-4)(tree-7-4),
    fill=blue!20,rounded corners,draw=blue,line width=1pt]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here is another method to position your nodes (using `positioning` instead of `matrix`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
  \tikzset{
    on grid,
    node distance=1cm and 3.5cm,
    col4/.style={fill=cyan!20,draw,rounded corners},
    every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},
  }
  % first column
  \node (n-0-0) at (-5,-3) {$^0S_0$};

  % second column
  \node[above right=of n-0-0] (n-1-0) {$^{\Delta t}S_0$};
  \node[below right=of n-0-0] (n-1-1) {$^{\Delta t}S_1$};

  % third column
  \node[above right=of n-1-0] (n-2-0) {$^{2\Delta t}S_0$};
  \node[below right=of n-1-0] (n-2-1) {$^{2\Delta t}S_1$};
  \node[below right=of n-1-1] (n-2-2) {$^{2\Delta t}S_2$};

  % fourth column
  \node[col4,above right=of n-2-0] (n-3-0) {$^{\tau}S_0$};
  \node[col4,below right=of n-2-0] (n-3-1) {$^{\tau}S_1$};
  \node[col4,below right=of n-2-1] (n-3-2) {$^{\tau}S_2$};
  \node[col4,below right=of n-2-2] (n-3-3) {$^{\tau}S_2$};

  \draw[->] (n-0-0) -- (n-1-0) node [midway,above] {$p$};
  \draw[->] (n-0-0) -- (n-1-1) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
  \foreach \col in {1,2}{
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextcol}{\col+1}
    \foreach \line in {0,...,\col}{
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nextline}{\line + 1}
      \draw[->] (n-\col-\line) -- (n-\nextcol-\line);
      \draw[->] (n-\col-\line) -- (n-\nextcol-\nextline);
    }
  }

  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \node[fit=(n-3-0)(n-3-3),inner sep=.5em,
    fill=blue!20,rounded corners,draw=blue,line width=1pt]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution with the new [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package (this question gave me the opportunity to use it for the first time: couldn't resist, but I'm sure the answer could be improved). The idea behind is quite simple: the area to be highlighted is determined by a set of coordinate, that actually are the nodes of the matrix and it has been filled in `background` with the dedicated library.

The solutions provided by Paul Gaborit work pretty well, but I was intrigued by the fact of highlighting not only columns, but sparse elements in the tree.

The following example contains two parts highlighted: the one needed by the OP and three other nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds, hobby,calc}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
      \matrix (tree) [%
        matrix of nodes,
        minimum size=1cm,
        column sep=3.5cm,
        row sep=1cm,
      ]
      {
                &                    &                     &  $^\tau S_0$     \\
                &                    &  $^{2\Delta t}S_0$  &              \\
                & $^{\Delta t}S_0$   &                     &  $^\tau S_1$     \\
        $^0S_0$ &                    &  $^{2\Delta t}S_1$  &              \\
                & $^{\Delta t}S_1$  &                      &  $^\tau S_2$     \\
                &                    &  $^{2\Delta t}S_2$  &              \\
                &                    &                     &  $^\tau S_2$     \\
      };
      \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
      \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
      \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};

    \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
      \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    % the requested case
    \draw[blue,fill=cyan!15,xscale=1.725] (tree-1-4.west) to[closed,curve through={(tree-1-4.north) .. (tree-1-4.east) .. (tree-7-4.east)..(tree-7-4.south).. (tree-7-4.west) }] (tree-1-4.west);

    % another case

   \draw[blue,fill=cyan!15,xscale=1.1] (tree-5-2.west) to[closed,curve through={([tension in=1.4]$(tree-5-2.west)!0.5!(tree-4-3.west)$)..([tension in=-0.75]tree-4-3.west)..(tree-2-3.west)..(tree-2-3.north)..(tree-2-3.east) .. ([tension in=-0.1]tree-4-3.east)..(tree-5-2.south east)}] (tree-5-2.west);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Won't transfer the correct answer, but thank you.

Comment: Great answer, Claudio! `:)`

Answer (score 8):

I think I found a really interesting solution because of the simplicity.

The idea is the construction of a path that simply go through the nodes of interest. To highlight, the path must have width greater than the nodes. This path should be in a back layer to not cover the nodes.

Here is the result:

[image: Path highlight]

And the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\tikzset{
    my box/.style = {
        , line cap = round
        , line join = round
    }
}

\newcommand{\highlight}[3]{
    \path [my box, line width = #1, draw = #2] #3;

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\innerlinewidth}{0.9 * #1}
    \path [my box, line width = \innerlinewidth, draw = #2!20] #3;
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \matrix (tree) [%
            matrix of nodes,
            minimum size=1cm,
            column sep=3.5cm,
            row sep=1cm,
        ] {
                    &                   &                     &  $^\tau S_0$ \\
                    &                   &  $^{2\Delta t}S_0$  &              \\
                    & $^{\Delta t}S_0$  &                     &  $^\tau S_1$ \\
            $^0S_0$ &                   &  $^{2\Delta t}S_1$  &              \\
                    & $^{\Delta t}S_1$  &                     &  $^\tau S_2$ \\
                    &                   &  $^{2\Delta t}S_2$  &              \\
                    &                   &                     &  $^\tau S_2$ \\
        };

        \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-3-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};
        \draw[->] (tree-4-1) -- (tree-5-2) node [midway,below] {$1-p$};
        \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-2-3) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-3-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,below] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-4-3) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-5-2) -- (tree-6-3) node [midway,below] {};

        \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-1-4) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-2-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,below] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-3-4) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-4-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,below] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-5-4) node [midway,above] {};
        \draw[->] (tree-6-3) -- (tree-7-4) node [midway,below] {};

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \highlight{12mm}{blue}{(tree-2-3.center) -- (tree-4-3.center) -- (tree-5-2.center)}
            \highlight{20mm}{green}{(tree-1-4.center) -- (tree-3-4.center) -- (tree-5-4.center) -- (tree-7-4.center)}
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And thus, we can obtain other types of results using the library decoration. Some examples below.

The result with snake decoration:

[image: Snake path]

And the tikzset code:

```
\tikzset{
    my box/.style = {
        , line cap = round
        , line join = round
        , decorate
        , decoration = {
            snake
            , segment length = 20mm
            , amplitude = 1mm
        }
    }
}
```

Another result, with random steps:

[image: Random steps path]

And the tikzset code:

```
\tikzset{
    my box/.style = {
        , line cap = round
        , line join = round
        , decorate
        , decoration = {
            random steps
            , segment length = 10mm
            , amplitude = 1mm
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. You can also use a double line to get the path drawn only once which would make this even more concise : `\path [my box, line width=0.2*#1,double, double distance=0.9*#1,double=#2!20, draw, #2] #3;`

Comment: Thanks, @percusse! I did not know this feature. Where can I find more information about it?

Comment: You can find it in the [TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/Tikz) page 160 for the version 2.10.

Comment: Wow: absolutely nice!!