# Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-trees, highlighting

To make it simple, I want to highlight a group of tikz nodes like in the following picture

[image]

It was borrowed from the [JLatexEditor](http://jlatexeditor.endrullis.de/wiki/TreeMagic). I would like to know which Tikz commands I can use to do the job in order to automatize this task for several trees I have to make. It is important to keep the blending effect of colors like in node g. Here is the MWE also borrowed from [JLatexEditor](http://jlatexeditor.endrullis.de/wiki/TreeMagic):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,trees}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g}
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27185/3954) to [padded boundary of convex hull](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27171/3954) and layers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,trees}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}


\newcommand{\convexpath}[2]{
[   
    create hullnodes/.code={
        \global\edef\namelist{#1}
        \foreach [count=\counter] \nodename in \namelist {
            \global\edef\numberofnodes{\counter}
            \node at (\nodename) [draw=none,name=hullnode\counter] {};
        }
        \node at (hullnode\numberofnodes) [name=hullnode0,draw=none] {};
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastnumber{\numberofnodes+1}
        \node at (hullnode1) [name=hullnode\lastnumber,draw=none] {};
    },
    create hullnodes
]
($(hullnode1)!#2!-90:(hullnode0)$)
\foreach [
    evaluate=\currentnode as \previousnode using \currentnode-1,
    evaluate=\currentnode as \nextnode using \currentnode+1
    ] \currentnode in {1,...,\numberofnodes} {
  let
    \p1 = ($(hullnode\currentnode)!#2!-90:(hullnode\previousnode)$),
    \p2 = ($(hullnode\currentnode)!#2!90:(hullnode\nextnode)$),
    \p3 = ($(\p1) - (hullnode\currentnode)$),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y3,\x3)},
    \p4 = ($(\p2) - (hullnode\currentnode)$),
    \n2 = {atan2(\y4,\x4)},
    \n{delta} = {-Mod(\n1-\n2,360)}
  in 
    {-- (\p1) arc[start angle=\n1, delta angle=\n{delta}, radius=#2] -- (\p2)}
}
-- cycle
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g} 
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
    }
  };
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\fill[red,opacity=0.3] \convexpath{a,g,b}{8pt};
\fill[blue,opacity=0.3] \convexpath{g,f,h,c,h,f}{8pt};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: I found a particularity of your method that I think it is worth signaling in this post. The nodes have to be enumerated in the order of the clockwise direction (As it was stated in Jake's question). Otherwise, it will render a wrong convex hull. So, `\convexpath{a,g,b}` is correct, but `\convexpath{a,b,g}` is not.

Answer (score 27):

The use of the [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package here leads to a very similar result to the picture posted by the OP:

[image]

I was in doubt if posting this answer because it's pretty much the same of the one given in [Highlighting some nodes of a TikZ binomial tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70648/highlighting-some-nodes-of-a-tikz-binomial-tree/70653#70653), but it could be seen as a better example of use of the [`hobby`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hobby) package. The point is that in the answer [Highlighting some nodes of a TikZ binomial tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70648/highlighting-some-nodes-of-a-tikz-binomial-tree/70653#70653) several `[tension in]`s were used, but I saw that the result could be improved by simply adding more *points* along the curve. This from one hand complicate a bit the path definition, but I think is a good price to pay seeing the result.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,backgrounds,calc,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (f) {f}
    child { node (g) {g}
      child { node (a) {a}
    }
      child { node (b) {b}
    }
  }
    child { node (h) {h}
      child { node (c) {c}
    }
  };

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
  \draw[blue,fill=blue,opacity=0.2](f.north) to[closed,curve through={($(f.south west)!0.5!(g.north west)$) .. (g.south west) .. (h.south west) .. (c.south west) .. (c.south east) .. ($(c.north east)!0.5!(h.south east)$) .. (h.east).. ($(h.north east)!0.5!(f.south east)$)}](f.north);
  \draw[red,fill=red,opacity=0.2](g.north) to[closed,curve through={($(g.south west)!0.5!(a.north west)$) .. (a.south west) .. (a.south east) ..(b.south west) .. (b.south east) .. ($(b.north east)!0.5!(g.south east)$) }] (g.north);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Woah, that looks really good! Can you combine that with the convex hull approach so you only need to provide the list of nodes that you want enveloped?

Comment: Thanks Jake, but the most of the credit should go to Andrew's great package `:)` Regarding the question: yes, it's really a good idea. I'll have a look as soon as possible!

Comment: Your method renders a much better looking output, but I really need the task to be automatized like @Gonzalo Medina did with `\convexpath{a,g,b}{8pt}`. I'll keep Gonzalo's answer as the accepted one. But I will really love to see a combination of both solutions like @Jake proposes.

Comment: @Jake: I did a trial, but my bad math background does not helped too much `:)`; I followed exactly your procedure in two directions basically: at first I still adopted the `arc` to draw the path around a single node (see http://imgur.com/Oy9z3) while in a second moment I tried to remove it (no image uploaded for decency `:D`). My intuition indeed is that removing the `arc` path by substituting it in some other manner will help, but I have no idea about it. Should I open a question?

Comment: I vote for opening a question!

Comment: @FelipeAguirre: new question opened [Hobby path realization in convex hull approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/hobby-path-realization-in-convex-hull-approach).

Comment: I love this community, thank you for existing!