# Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-trees

Is it possible to extend the approach of the question:

[Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/highlight-a-group-of-nodes-in-a-tikz-tree)

to a generic tikz graph? In particular I don't have a graph in form of a tree, so I can't specify the relations.

In my example, I would like to specify the nodes that form a partition of a graph, something like the following image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can be interested in [Hobby path realization in convex hull approach](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71638/13304) and [Highlight a group of nodes in a tikz tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70999/13304).

Comment: I know about the group of nodes highlighting in tikz-tree but my question was explicitly how to do if the graph I'm doing it's not a tree.

Comment: I could also specify the position of the nodes manually, so no need of graph drawing packages, but the problem is how to draw a shape (possibly with different colors) that contains a given set of nodes automatically. The tikz-tree solution is what I'm trying to achieve but with no hope, because I'm not drawing trees. I'm also not experienced in tikz so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The first proposal I was mentioning works with TikZ nodes, does not matter whether they are created in form of a tree.

Comment: Please post your code for the graph so that people can try to help you. Right now, you are asking for help highlighting the nodes but in order to help, people have to draw the graph of nodes themselves first. That's a lot of setting up just in order to recreate the problem which you've already created. Much better give people the problem and let them put their efforts into solving it.