# fit irregular set of nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-node

Is there any automated way to tightly fit an irregular set (say tree-shaped) of nodes in TikZ?

The standard approach (using `fit = (v1) (v2) ... (vk)`) uses predefined shapes (eg. circle or rectangle) that might include vertices outside the desired set v1,v2,...,vk.

Comment: no, with `fit` you can only use standard node shapes (rectangle, ellipse, circle, cloud, ... ), so, you should in such a cases draw curve "by hand" :-(

Comment: These may be of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70999/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71638/

Comment: Well, i think that the main point of the question is precisely that the set of target nodes does not need to be convex (after all, most available shapes with fit are convex.