# Tree graphic using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I want to mimic the tree of the picture, but i can not understand from tikz manual how to do some things:

- aligned lines (the should not start from the upper center of the node point)
- perfectly squared lines: i want all the angles to be 90°: now i just aproximate them with the `\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=14mm,sibling distance=25mm]` command.
- i'd like the dashed line to start with a little continuous line, and possibly to end with a dot under the h_i label: i tried on the top right to add another (empty) node, but in this way the continuous line is too long.

How should i do these edits?

[image: Tree model]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here my MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\footnotesize]
\tikzset{
    solid node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black},
    hollow node/.style={}
}

\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=14mm,sibling distance=25mm]

\node[solid node,label=right:{$\phi$},label=left:{$t_0$}]{} [grow=up]
child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\phi$}] {}
    child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\phi$}]{}
            child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\phi$}]{}
                child{
                    %node[solid node,label=right:{$\phi$}] {}
                    child{node[hollow node,label=45:{$h_\omega$}] {}    edge from parent[dashed]}
                    child[missing]
                }   
                child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
                    child[missing]
                    child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
                        child[missing]
                        child {node[hollow node,label=135:{$h_3$}] {}   edge from parent[dashed]
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
            child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
                child[missing]
                child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
                    child[missing]
                    child {node[hollow node,label=135:{$h_2$}] {}   edge from parent[dashed]
                    }   
                }
            }
    }
    child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
        child[missing]
        child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
            child[missing]
            child {node[hollow node,label=135:{$h_1$}] {}   edge from parent[dashed]
            }   
        }
    }
}
child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
    child[missing]
    child {node[solid node,label=right:{$\neg\phi$}] {}
    child[missing]
    child {node[hollow node,label=135:{$h_0$}] {}       edge from parent[dashed]
    }   
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: My first draw]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397446/how-to-highlight-some-portion-of-binary-tree, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395037/forest-tree-not-symmetric

Comment: @StefanPinnow done. :)

Comment: @Andrew thanks, but i'm trying with a different approach, i guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use `tikz-qtree` for such a simple graph.

I suggest to you a solution with `\foreach` and an ordinary positioning:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,
        every node/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1,fill=black}]
    \node[label=right:{$\phi$},label=left:{$t_{0}$}](p0){};
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i - 1)] in {1,2,3} {
        \node[label=below right:{$\phi$}, above right= of p\j](p\i){};
        \draw (p\j) -- (p\i);   
    }
    \node[above right= of p3, label=above right:{$h_{\omega}$}] (p4) {};
    \draw (p3) -- ($(p3)!0.3!(p4)$) edge[dashed] (p4);
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3}{   
        \coordinate (pl0\i) at (p\i);
        \foreach \il [evaluate=\il as \jl using int(\il - 1)] in {1,2} {
            \node[label={$\neg\phi$}, above left= of pl\jl\i](pl\il\i){};
            \draw (pl\jl\i) -- (pl\il\i);   
        }
        \node[above left= of pl2\i, label=above left:{$h_{\i}$}] (end\i) {};
        \draw (pl2\i) -- ($(pl2\i)!0.3!(end\i)$) edge[dashed] (end\i);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is perfect! I will try to understand how you did it, how you use positioning and the \foreach command! Thank you so much!

Comment: @mattinodigitale It's simpler that it seems, I just used `above right= of` and `above left= of`. The `p` or `pl` followed by the index are only the name of the nodes. You could also add a lenght after `=`. If you need some explanation, just ask, we are here to help. Thank you for accepting my answer!