# Custom Dynkin diagram arrow tips

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows

Being aware of the excellent package [dynkin-diagrams](https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams) by [Benjamin McKay](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19327/benjamin-mckay), I still need something else, since there are several customizations that have been kindly provided in an answer to my previous question [How to draw a border around a subset of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415804/48166) here by the former TeX.SE user marmot which I need to use.

So what I would like is to draw in TikZ arrows of shape `=>=`, and I mean *literally* of this exact shape (except that the `=` segments might need some stretching), and the same for triple arrows.

Although the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) has lots of details about arrow tips, I could not find instructions for this particular kind. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

With the 6 April 2021 release of the dynkin-diagrams package, you get:
[image]

just by adding [Bourbaki-arrow] as an option to the package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[Bourbaki-arrow]{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
\dynkin F4

\dynkin G2
\end{document}
```

Old answer:
Just for Dynkin diagrams. I am not sure if you want straight lines or arcs (like the default for the Dynkin diagrams package), so here is the package standard arrow, along with two options:

[image: Dynkin diagrams with arrows in three styles]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
name = jibladze,
parameters = { \the\pgfarrowlength },
setup code = {},
drawing code = {
  \pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
      \pgfsetroundjoin   % fix join
  \pgfsetroundcap    % fix cap
  \pgfsetlinewidth{5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{white}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{\pgfarrowlength}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-\pgfarrowlength}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  \pgfsetlinewidth{.2\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{\pgfarrowlength}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{-\pgfarrowlength}}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
},
defaults = { length = 2pt }
}

\pgfdeclarearrow{
name = mamuka,
parameters = { \the\pgfarrowlength },
setup code = {},
drawing code = {
  \pgfsetdash{}{0pt} % do not dash
  \pgfsetroundjoin   % fix join
  \pgfsetroundcap    % fix cap
  \pgfsetlinewidth{5\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{white}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{\pgfarrowlength}}
  \pgfpatharc{180}{270}{\pgfarrowlength}
  \pgfpatharc{90}{180}{\pgfarrowlength}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
  \pgfsetlinewidth{.2\pgflinewidth}
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{black}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.75\pgfarrowlength}{\pgfarrowlength}}
  \pgfpatharc{180}{270}{\pgfarrowlength}
  \pgfpatharc{90}{180}{\pgfarrowlength}
  \pgfusepathqstroke
},
defaults = { length = 2pt }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\dynkin G2\\
\dynkin[arrow shape/.style={-{jibladze}}]G2\\
\dynkin[arrow shape/.style={-{mamuka}}]G2\\
\dynkin F4\\
\dynkin[arrow shape/.style={-{jibladze}}]F4\\
\dynkin[arrow shape/.style={-{mamuka}}]F4
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To make jibladze the default for the entire file, you can just write \tikzset{/Dynkin diagram/arrow shape/.style={-{jibladze}}} near the top of the file.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ben! The one with straight lines is absolutely perfect for me. The reason I prefer it is simply that I remember from somewhere the mnemonics: a thing like `A=>=B` tells that the root `A` is longer than the root `B`, so you can read `>` as the symbol for "greater".

Answer (score 2):

It's a tikz picture component, rather than an arrow.

The `>` is a Classical TikZ arrowhead, the `=` likely is a `thin, double` edge between two nodes.

I don't (currently have time to) understand the (heavily parameterized) dynkin package code -- so not an answer -- but here is a very simplistic off-the-cuff thematic re-interpretation (not necessarily accurate) of such a construct:

[image: pseudo-arrow]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows.meta,
    positioning,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node [circle,fill=black,radius=2pt,draw,label=A] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node [circle,fill=black,radius=2pt,draw,label=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\node [label=C] (C) at (1.5,0) {};
\node [circle,fill=black,radius=2pt,draw,label=D] (D) at (2,0) {};
\draw[thin] (A) -- (B);
\draw[thin,double] (C.west) -- (D);
\draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[red,length=1mm,]},thin,double,] (B) -- (C.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could emulate a `=>=` arrow using invisible nodes, for example like so:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt]
\node [label=B] (B) at (1,0) {};
\node [label=C] (C) at (1.5,0) {};
\node [label=D] (D) at (2,0) {};
\draw[thin,double] (C.west) -- (D);
\draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[red,length=1mm,]},thin,double,] (B) -- (C.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: arrow only]

Comment: Let me just wait, maybe somebody proposes something more concise. In the meanwhile, your solution is quite acceptable and I already realized it. I just modified it slightly, doing `\node (>) at (1.5,0) {\tiny\texttt>};` and `\draw[double] (B) -- (>) -- (D);`.

Comment: Sorry for accepting another one, although it is definitely less concise than yours. It just looks more... erm... wholesome?