# I want to draw a 3-hyperlink (hyperedge with four nodes) as shown below? I have also included the code for my attempt at that

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

[image]

```
\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths,calc, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define the nodes and their positions
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v1) at (1,0) {$v_1$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v2) at (3,0) {$v_2$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v3) at (2,1.732) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v4) at (2,-1.732) {$v_4$};

    % Draw the shape and fill it
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \filldraw[fill=yellow!70] ($(v1) + (-0.5,0)$)
                to[out=90,in=180] ($(v1) + (0.5, 0.5)$)
                to[out=0,in=270] ($(v3) + (-0.5, 0)$)
                to[out=90,in=180] ($(v3) + (0, 0.5)$)
                to[out=0,in=90] ($(v3) + (0.5, 0.0)$)
                to[out=270,in=180] ($(v2) + (-0.5, 0.5)$)
                to[out=0,in=90] ($(v2) + (0.5, 0)$)
                to[out=270,in=0] ($(v2) + (-0.5, -0.5)$)
                to[out=180,in=90] ($(v4) + (0.5, 0.0)$)
                to[out=270,in=0] ($(v4) + (0.0, -0.5)$)
                to[out=180,in=270] ($(v4) + (-0.5, 0.0)$)
                to[out=90,in=0] ($(v1) + (0.5, -0.5)$)
                to[out=180,in=270] ($(v1) + (-0.5,0)$);
                
                
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Also, is there a better way to draw this figure? The above `tikz` code produces the following figure.

[image]

Comment: [Q27171](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27171), [Q70999](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70999), [Q71638](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71638/16595)

Comment: Can you update the title of your question to include what your question is about so future users with the same problem will be able to find your post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `star` node with `rounded corners`. Play around with `minimum size` and `star point ratio` until you get what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw, circle, fill=blue!40, minimum size=5mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[star, star points =4, star point ratio=1.7, draw, rounded corners=5mm, minimum size=3.2cm, fill=red!20] at (0,0) {};
\node[mynode] at (0,1){};
\node[mynode] at (1,0){};
\node[mynode] at (0,-1){};
\node[mynode] at (-1,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice +1 :)

Answer (score 6):

Nice solution you posted.

Here's a sketch for an alternative approach. It doesn't necessarily do with less code, but perhaps gives you more options. Main ideas:

Use the `fit` library. Next, define node `Fit` , which contains your 4 nodes, but don't draw it. Increase its `inner sep`aration, as we'd like to reuse its anchors.

```
        % ~~~ this nodes rectangle contains all 4 ~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[fit=(v1) (v2) (v3) (v4), inner sep=7mm] (Fit) {};
```

Finally, draw your path, using anchors like `(Fit.west)` etc. with drawing options you like. For a more complicated yellow area you may want to define e.g. 4 more points, e.g. by using `midway` and related (see manual). *(E.g. use asymmetric controls with the 4 anchor points for a wild asymmetric shape around v1-v4.)* `controls` give you more control over the swings (Bezier curves; yes, I simplify french writing). // Being lazy, for demonstration purposes, I just draw the path with `rounded corners`.

```
        % ~~~ now draw a shape using its anchors ~~~~~
        %     refine this path as needed, e.g. by defining
        %     midway positions and use controls (Bezier) rather than angles
        \draw[fill=yellow!70,rounded corners=1cm] (Fit.west) -- (Fit.north) -- (Fit.east) -- (Fit.south) -- cycle;
```

Those controls are better to control, once you understood the gliding lines between the 4 points specified:

- dashed: running with parameter t
- green: interconnected; again run with t
- blue: interconnecting
- point on curve: at t's value on blue interconnect

[image: bezier]

[image: result]

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687673/i-want-to-draw-the-attached-figure-shown-below-i-have-also-included-the-code-fo

\documentclass[crop, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths,calc, backgrounds,fit}% <<<

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture} % one way to do it
    % Define the nodes and their positions
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v1) at (1,0) {$v_1$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v2) at (3,0) {$v_2$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v3) at (2,1.732) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v4) at (2,-1.732) {$v_4$};

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % ~~~ this nodes rectangle contains all 4 ~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[fit=(v1) (v2) (v3) (v4), inner sep=7mm] (Fit) {};
        % ~~~ now draw a shape using its anchors ~~~~~
        %     refine this path as needed, e.g. by defining
        %     midway positions and use controls (Bezier) rather than angles
        \draw[fill=yellow!70,rounded corners=1cm] (Fit.west) -- (Fit.north) -- (Fit.east) -- (Fit.south) -- cycle;
    \end{pgfonlayer}    
    
 \end{tikzpicture}


 \begin{tikzpicture} % posted solution
    % Define the nodes and their positions
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v1) at (1,0) {$v_1$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v2) at (3,0) {$v_2$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v3) at (2,1.732) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v4) at (2,-1.732) {$v_4$};

    % Draw the shape and fill it
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \filldraw[fill=yellow!70] ($(v1) + (-0.5,0)$)
                to[out=90,in=180] ($(v1) + (0.5, 0.5)$)
                to[out=0,in=270] ($(v3) + (-0.5, 0)$)
                to[out=90,in=180] ($(v3) + (0, 0.5)$)
                to[out=0,in=90] ($(v3) + (0.5, 0.0)$)
                to[out=270,in=180] ($(v2) + (-0.5, 0.5)$)
                to[out=0,in=90] ($(v2) + (0.5, 0)$)
                to[out=270,in=0] ($(v2) + (-0.5, -0.5)$)
                to[out=180,in=90] ($(v4) + (0.5, 0.0)$)
                to[out=270,in=0] ($(v4) + (0.0, -0.5)$)
                to[out=180,in=270] ($(v4) + (-0.5, 0.0)$)
                to[out=90,in=0] ($(v1) + (0.5, -0.5)$)
                to[out=180,in=270] ($(v1) + (-0.5,0)$);                               
    \end{pgfonlayer}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**P.S.**: As an add-on, here's a way to introduce 4 coordinates explicitly.

As indicated inside the code you now have 4 parameters to vary appearance:

- Parameter 1: angles of polar coordinates
- Parameter 2: radius of polar coordinates
- Parameter 3: this nodes inner separation `(Fit)`
- Parameter 4: radius of rounded corners

While being lazy I used a `\foreach` loop to define 4 angles, and a counter `\i`, which helps naming the coordinates names.

```
 % ~~~ defining 4 extra points ~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \a [count=\i] in {50, 140, 230, 310}% <<< Parameter 1: angles of polar coordinates
        \coordinate (c\i) at (\a:1.1);% <<<< Parameter 2: radius of polar coordinates
```

[image: result2]

```
 \begin{tikzpicture} % second way to do it
    % Define the nodes and their positions
    % ~~~ shifted to the left ~~~ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v1) at (-1,0) {$v_1$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v2) at (1,0) {$v_2$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v3) at (0,1.732) {$v_3$};
    \node[draw,circle,fill=blue!40] (v4) at (0,-1.732) {$v_4$};
    
    % ~~~ defining 4 extra points ~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \a [count=\i] in {50, 140, 230, 310}% <<< Parameter 1: angles of polar coordinates
        \coordinate (c\i) at (\a:1.1);% <<<< Parameter 2: radius of polar coordinates

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        % ~~~ this nodes rectangle contains all 4 ~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[fit=(v1) (v2) (v3) (v4), inner sep=13mm] (Fit) {};% <<< Parameter 3: this nodes inner separation
        % ~~~ now draw a shape using its anchors ~~~~~
        %     refine this path as needed, e.g. by defining
        %     midway positions and use controls (Bezier) rather than angles
        \draw[fill=yellow!70,rounded corners=10mm] % <<< Parameter 4: radius of rounded corners
                    (Fit.west) -- (c2) -- (Fit.north) -- (c1) -- 
                    (Fit.east) -- (c4) --  (Fit.south) -- (c3) -- cycle;
        % ~~~ just to show the 4 extra coordinates ~~~
        \draw[fill=orange!70] (c2) -- (c1) -- (c4)  -- (c3) -- cycle;       
    \end{pgfonlayer}        
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[cyan!20] (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 3 cm);
        \fill[cyan!20] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 1.5 cm);
        \foreach \i in {0,90,180,270}
         \fill[blue] (\i:2.3) circle(.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```