# Drawing shapes around Tikz Tree nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

I have a Tikz tree in my Latex document as follows:

```
% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=4.5cm, sibling distance=6.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=4cm, sibling distance=2.5cm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=8em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{atom} = [draw=black,thick]

% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[bag] {$S_0 = 1$}
    child {
        node[bag] {$S_1 = 0.90$}        
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.810$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_3$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.900$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_2$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.918$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_1$}
            }
            edge from parent 
            node[above] {$Y_1 = y_3$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {$S_1 = 1.00$}        
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.900$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_3$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.000$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_2$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.020$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_1$}
            }
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$Y_1 = y_2$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {$S_1 = 1.02$}        
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.918$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_3$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.020$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_2$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.0404$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_1$}
            }
        edge from parent         
            node[above] {$Y_1 = y_1$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With result:

[image]

I would like to draw rounded rectangles around the end nodes of each of the three first-level children. There would therefore be three nodes in each rectangle, with the top three in the first, middle three in the second, and lower three in the last. I would also like labels vertically centered on the right of each rectangle. The final result should be as so:

[image: What I would like]

As I am completely new to Tikz, I do not know how to achieve this result. Help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).   While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: You should be able to use the `fit` `tikz` library to achieve this.  See for example the tutorial style answer at [how to draw a container box in latex around automata?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75497/how-to-draw-a-container-box-in-latex-around-automata/75498#75498).

Comment: Similar question: [Highlighting some nodes of a TikZ binomial tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70648/highlighting-some-nodes-of-a-tikz-binomial-tree).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The idea (as **Peter Grill** suggested in a comment) is to name the necessary nodes and to use the `fit` library; auxiliary nodes were used; a simple loop draws the three frames and places the labels; also I changed from the obsolete `\tikzstyle` to `\tikzset`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzset{
  level 1/.style={level distance=4.5cm, sibling distance=6.5cm},
  level 2/.style={level distance=4cm, sibling distance=2.5cm}
}

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzset{
  bag/.style = {text width=8em, text centered},
  end/.style = {circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt},
  atom/.style = {draw=black,thick}
}

% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[bag] {$S_0 = 1$}
    child {
        node[bag] {$S_1 = 0.90$}        
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.810$}] (b3) {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_3$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.900$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_2$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.918$}] (t3) {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_1$}
            }
            edge from parent 
            node[above] {$Y_1 = y_3$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {$S_1 = 1.00$}        
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.900$}] (b2) {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_3$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.000$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_2$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.020$}] (t2) {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_1$}
            }
            edge from parent         
            node[above] {$Y_1 = y_2$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {$S_1 = 1.02$}        
        child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 0.918$}] (b1) {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_3$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.020$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_2$}
            }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$S_2 = 1.0404$}] (t1) {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$Y_2 = y_1$}
            }
        edge from parent         
            node[above] {$Y_1 = y_1$}
    };
\begin{scope}[label distance=6mm,]
\foreach \i/\label in {1/Label 1,2/Label 2,3/Label 3}
{
  \coordinate  (aux\i) at ([xshift=2cm]t\i);
  \node[inner sep=6pt,rounded corners=6pt,draw,red,fit={(t\i) (b\i) (aux\i)},label=right:{\color{red}\label}] {};
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, but gives me the warning 
"No argument following \label" in the foreach loop.

Comment: @lodhb if the *exact* code I posted gives you warnings, most probably your LaTeX system is outdated. What LaTeX distribution and version do you use?

Comment: Yes it is the exact same code. I am using MiKTeX 2.9.4476
, downloaded last week.

Comment: @lodhb Ah, I see. I use TeX Live2012 and (besides an overfull \hbox warning) the code runs OK in my system. No idea why it generates the warning you mention in your system (I haven't used MikTeX in a long while). Fortunately the warning seems to be harmless.

Comment: Perfectly harmless, I just have a natural aversion to warnings and errors :-) thanks again!