# How to add arrow to connect between node Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have the block nodes as below figure. I want to connect them by arrow, with bold font. Could you help me to look at my code and update them? Thank you so much

This is my current result

[image]

This is my expected result

[image]

One more thing, the graph does not show the center of page. Is it possible to adjust its position?

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={draw, rectangle},
edge from parent path={
(\tikzparentnode) |-   % Start from parent
($(\tikzparentnode)!0.5!(\tikzchildnode)$) -| % make an ortho line to mid point
(\tikzchildnode)},
second/.style   ={level distance=18ex},
third/.style   ={level distance=18ex},
fourth/.style   ={level distance=10ex},
]                            % make another ortho to the target

  \node (A){This is first block}
  [sibling distance=9cm]
  child {node (B) {\begin{varwidth}{6cm}The second block 1\end{varwidth}}
  [sibling distance=6cm]
    child [third]{node {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Third level block left 2\end{varwidth}}
    [sibling distance=3cm]
         child [fourth]{node  {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Last block 1\end{varwidth}}}         
         child [fourth]{node {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Last block 2\end{varwidth}}}
    }
    child [second]{node {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Third level block left 2\end{varwidth}}
    [sibling distance=3cm]
         child [fourth]{node  {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Last block 3\end{varwidth}}}         
         child [fourth]{node {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Last block 4\end{varwidth}}}
    }
  }
  child {node {The second block 2}
  [sibling distance=3.5cm]
    child [third]{node {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Third level block right 1\end{varwidth}}}
    child [third]{node {\begin{varwidth}{3cm}Third level block right 2\end{varwidth}}}
  };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

UPDATE: Regarding the ans. of smike. I Obtained the result as below. But it has two problem
1. The figure did not center of the page

2. The width line of block look more thick. I want all blocks have same thick

[image]

Comment: Since you are using child nodes, you can edit the overall style for it:

\tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,->}}.

I am not sure why the centering is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, it is correct. As I shown in figure, the whole tree looks move to right side, I want to center it in the page.

Comment: Could it be that you are using too wide sibling distances?

Comment: And if I want to adjust the connected line between them more thick, I will use \tikzset{edge from parent/.style={draw,->,thick}}, Is it right? I do it but the line does not show the thick line

Comment: `ultra thick` might show better. Or using a custom line width can also be done: `line width=1.5pt`.

Comment: I uses the sibling distances to control the distance between blocks. Due to having many block, I need use them more large to ignore the overlapping between blocks

Comment: The line is thick now. But the bocks at third and last level are also thick, It makes wrong. I only want the line connection is thick

Comment: For those specific blocks, you can pass the command to their nodes: `line width=x`, where `x` is the width you want. You can use scope here for that.

Comment: Regarding the centring, when I use the `geometry` package, your graph is automatically centred. That might help.

To be sure of that, pass the option `framed` to `tikzpicture` (remember to include `backgrounds` tikzlibrary). The frame around the graph will give you an idea of the placement of the figure with respect to the page.

Comment: I had a few questions: Should the children of a node be at the same level? Are you including this graph in a document eventually, or would you be interested in having a `standalone` version?

Comment: Yes. It need the same level. I am using the elsarticle template. I included the graph in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt at getting the right alignment of the overall graph, along with relevant arrow styles:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees,calc,backgrounds}

\newcommand{\vtext}[2]{
\begin{varwidth}{#1}%
\centering{#2}
\end{varwidth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed,
every node/.style={draw, rectangle},
edge from parent path={
(\tikzparentnode) |- ($(\tikzparentnode)!0.5!(\tikzchildnode)$) -| (\tikzchildnode)},
second/.style={level distance=18ex},%
third/.style={level distance=18ex},%
fourth/.style={level distance=10ex},%
level 1/.style={sibling distance=7cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm},
newlevel/.style={level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm}},
edge from parent/.style={draw,line width=1pt,->},
every node/.style={thin,draw}
]
\node (A){This is first block}[sibling distance=8cm]
child {node (B) {\vtext{6cm}{The second block 1}}
    child[third] {node {\vtext{2cm}{Third level block left 2}}
        child[fourth] {node {\vtext{2cm}{Last block 1}}}
        child[fourth] {node {\vtext{2cm}{Last block 2}}}
}
child[second] {node {\vtext{3cm}{Third level block right 2}}
    child[fourth] {node {\vtext{2cm}{Last block 3}}}
    child[fourth] {node {\vtext{2cm}{Last block 4}}}}
}
child[newlevel] {node {The second block 2}
    child[third] {node {\vtext{3cm}{Third level block right 1}}}
    child[third] {node {\vtext{3cm}{Third level block right 2}}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Tree Graph]

You can remove the frame around your graph by deleting the `framed` option from `tikzpicture`. I had to adjust the spacing in `varwidth` environment to make sure all the children fit with proper page centering. Some of the tikzlibraries you included were not necessary here, but I am assuming you use it elsewhere in the document.

**EDIT**: This picture gives a better idea of centering. The page was coloured cyan, except for the `tikzpicture`.

[image: Tree Graph Coloured]