# Binomial pricing trees using tikz

Tags: tikz-trees

How do you make binomial pricing trees using tikz?
I mean a tree like the this, but with only three time periods.
[image]

Comment: Also with similar `trees`(?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70648/highlighting-some-nodes-of-a-tikz-binomial-tree?rq=1